# ggplot geom_line for specific factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is there a way to add a line for specific factor levels in ggplot?
this simple example could provide a base to explain what I'm trying to say. In this case I'd like to avoid plotting the last level.

```
ggplot(BOD, aes(x=factor(Time), y=demand, group=1)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Juanchi, it would help if you include a small example of the data you are working with in a format that is easy to copy-and-paste into R.

Comment: Please provide `BOD` (use `dput(BOD)`). Your expected output is not clear : your just want to remove the `7` from the x scale? Or remove the last point?

Comment: BOD is in the R base... it is not needed to include as dput()

Comment: I only want to remove the line, not the level from the axis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply create a new variable with an `NA`-value for `Time == 7`:

```
BOD$demand2[BOD$Time<7] <- BOD$demand[BOD$Time<7]
```

and then plot:

```
ggplot(BOD, aes(x=factor(Time), y=demand2, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic()
```

You could also do it on the fly by utilizing the functionality of the `data.table`-package:

```
library(data.table)
ggplot(data = as.data.table(BOD)[Time==7, demand := NA],
       aes(x=factor(Time), y=demand, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic()
```

---

To answer your comment, you could include the point at 7 as follows:

```
ggplot(BOD, aes(x=factor(Time), y=demand2, group=1)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=factor(Time), y=demand)) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thanks! do you know how to do if I want to keep the point at 7?